# Safari won't let me access hardware web front-ends anymore

Tags: macos, safari

I use to be able to login to most hardware, even after the message **This connection is not private** popped up. I just had to enter my admin password and I was fine but now this no longer works.

Anyone else with this issue? It works fine if I use Google Chrome.